# get integer value from mysql column which is varchar

Tags: php, mysql

My sql table `hotel` containes a column `price` which has values like `RS.50/-`,`AED 55` etc. How can I take integers that are `.50` or `55` from it.

My mysql query is:

```
select hotel_price from hotel where hotel_price<=5000
```

but here hotel price is like `rs.5000/-` or `AED 5000` etc

Comment: The only sane solution is to change the columns type to a numeric one if you want to be able to use mathematical operators on it. Creating some stored procedure for this might be possible, but _why_?

Comment: i need this column as varchar when i integrate it into websiteusing php

Comment: use mysql cast like that CAST(hotel_price AS int)

Comment: I don't see why using the columns value in php automatically means you have to stored it as a varchar type. Converting the value to whatever you like inside php would be trivial. But even if you insist in storing the full string, then make a second column of a numeric type to be able to use mathematical operators inside your sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Try storing the value and the currency in two separate columns - then you can do a numeric search on the value and print the currency when outputting the data.

You could strip all non numeric chars;

`$var = (int)preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $var);`

Comment: I _think_ the OPs issue is to use a mathematical operator on the column inside the `WHERE` clause shown.